# D3.js creating a color gradient world map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a homework and I was thinking how I could solve it.

I'm following THIS tutorial: http://bl.ocks.org/MaciejKus/61e9ff1591355b00c1c1caf31e76a668

I have this world map:
[World Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVUxV.png)

My goal is to add a gradient based on the temperature of each city (for the world map) to fill the map instead of filling an entire country with only 1 color

example based on 3 cities from russia:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMloT.jpg)

I have no ideia how to do it, but I'd like to hear some suggestions!

Comment: please can you include some code in your question so we can see what you're working with. Also if you've tried anything thus far that would be helpful to include as well!

Comment: You are looking to interpolate raster data based on point data - to do so you can use different approaches: splines, kriging, inverse distance, etc. This isn't something that D3 excels at - it is not intended to be a GIS engine, doing the interploation in ArcGIS or QGIS will be much easier.